# Angular JS ng-include binding issues

Tags: angularjs, angular-template

I have created a pager widget using template file which I am using twice in my HTML page. I have a select for go to page option and also links for previous and next page.

Problem is that when I use select box for updating current page its updated and then I use previous and next page links, the current page gets updated but select box doesn't get updated.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong. Is there any logical mistake in my approach to building a pager widget like this?

Controller Code:

```
 var gallery = angular.module('gallery', []);
    gallery.controller('ItemListCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
      /*  Pagination Code */
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.itemsPerPage = 24;
    $scope.total = 100;
    $scope.range = function(min, max, step){
      step = step || 1;
      var input = [];
      for (var i = min; i <= max; i += step) input.push(i);
      return input;
    };
    $scope.prevPage = function (){
      if($scope.currentPage > 1){
        $scope.currentPage--;
      }
    };
    $scope.nextPage = function (){
      if($scope.currentPage < $scope.pageCount()){
        $scope.currentPage++;
      }
    };
    $scope.pageCount = function (){
      return Math.ceil($scope.total / $scope.itemsPerPage);
    };
    $scope.setPage = function (n){
      if(n >= 0 && n <= $scope.pageCount()){
        $scope.currentPage = parseInt(n, 10);
      }
    };
  }]);
```

Here is the plnkr URL for reproducing the issue.

http://plnkr.co/edit/9LUJnVzWAS9BauyORQn5?p=preview

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The root cause is `ng-include` will create a separate scope for targeted element, so a quick fix to your code is adding `$parent` prefix to all scope objects.

```
<fieldset class="pager">
<div>Page {{$parent.currentPage}} of {{$parent.pageCount()}}</div>
<div>
<div>
<label>Go to page</label>
<select ng-model='$parent.currentPage' ng-change="$parent.setPage($parent.currentPage)">
<option ng-repeat="n in range(1,$parent.pageCount())" value="{{n}}" ng-selected="n === $parent.currentPage">{{n}}</option>
</select>
</div>
<div>
<a href ng-click="$parent.prevPage()">Previous Page</a>
&nbsp;|&nbsp; 
<a href ng-click="$parent.nextPage()">Next Page</a>
</div>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

Per Angular document [Understanding Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes), Scope inheritance won't work as you expected when you try 2-way data binding (i.e., form elements, ng-model) to a primitive. This issue with primitives can be easily avoided by following the "best practice" of always have a ['.' in your ng-models](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m)

Comment: I have read that adding $parent is kind of a hack. If you can tell me what is the angular way of creating such a widget what would be really helpful.

Comment: Angular way of dealing with scope inheritance is using `.` dot in your ng-models, like `$scope.info = { currentPage: 1, itemsPerPage : 24, total : 100}`, then in your view, access them as `info.currentpage`, `info.itemsPerPage`.

Comment: +1 .. Thanks a ton .. I was working on this for almost 3 hours .. but could not figure it out. using $parent fixed all my issues.

Comment: @Che `$parent` can be a workaround, but you'd better use `a.b` dot notation to solve this problem

Comment: I ended up taking the ng-include out as I had too many elements in my include to go back and start managing them with dot or $parent...I was only using it to make the html easier to understand.  You saved me on this one.