# ng-include scope issue without changing template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is a select box in my template that looks like this:

```
<form name="myForm" class="fixed-select">
   <select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect"
            ng-model="selectedItem">
      <option ng-repeat="program in programs"
              value="{{program.name}}">
         {{program.name}}
      </option>
   </select>
</form>
```

My template is just this:

```
<div ng-include="'/views/program/program.html'"></div>
```

Now, in my controller (let's call it MyCtrl) I can set selectedItem and cause the right thing to load:

```
$scope.selectedItem = "Manage";
```

But when using the selectbox manually nothing happens, as I believe it's not tied to the parent's scope (the current controller (MyCtrl) of the template with the ng-include).

I've been searching for how to fix this, and a few options mention changing the template to include $parent or something. Is that really necessary? I was hoping that ng-include was a great way to encapsulate existing data so I could use it again with no modifications. What do I have to do to hook up the ng-include scope to the controller (MyCtrl)?

Thank you very much for your time and patience in reading this.

edit1:
The 'programs' that the select box is populated with is just an array of strings: ["Main","Etc"]

Comment: you might want to start with changing the select to use `ng-options` which is made for option lists, instead of `ng-repeat`.

Comment: I've used ng-repeat before with no issues. ng-options screwed up the default option I wanted to load.

Comment: can you update the question a bit with the contents of the `programs` array so that the behavior you are describing can be verified?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I should have created an object to inherit from. So instead of `$scope.selectedItem` in my controller and just `selectedItem` in my template, I used `$scope.model.selectedItem` and `model.selectedItem` respectively.

I learned about this from [another issue on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28525717/angular-js-ng-include-binding-issues).